# Docker DNS Not Seeing External Servers

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I've been recently having hostname resolving issues with Docker Version 17.04-CE and I'm not sure what is causing it. I currently have docker setup not to use any options for when running, but lately my containers can no longer access google and any other hosts on the internet when connecting via domain names (IPV4 works fine and I can ping external IP's).

I've added dns: 8.8.8.8 into the docker-compose.yml for services and that is a bandaid, but when using any other docker-compose files (such as laradock) I can't ping or curl external servers. I can still curl other docker instances, and I can actually curl servers inside my intranet. Changing the /etc/resolv.conf manually inside the container works but I need it to work out of the box. Also, if I start a container normally with docker run -it example-container bash functionality works as expected.

docker-compose ran resolv.conf (docker-compose up -d nginx mysql && docker-compose exec workspace cat /etc/resolv.conf) - NOT WORKING

```
search machines.redacted.ca it.redacted.ca services.redacted.ca 
apps.redacted.ca
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

vanilla docker resolv.conf (docker-run -it mysql ping google.ca) - WORKING FINE

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search machines.redacted.ca it.redacted.ca services.redacted.ca 
apps.redacted.ca
nameserver 192.168.5.5 #Internal DNS server
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it ended up being that my internal DNS server was block recursive DNS queries. I tracked down the bug by setting up docker in debug mode, then monitored docker and the dns server logs. Docker seemed to be sending DNS queries fine, but it looked like Bind9 was spitting out errors about denying recursive queries. I googled the issue and change the setting below and everything worked again. I added the following to the bind9 configuration and it worked.

The weird thing was, one of my co-workers was using the same methodoligy but the queries worked fine for them. He was running a different distro, and a older version of docker and docker-compose though.

Named.conf.options:

```
options {
    ...




    allow-recursion { all; };

}
```